# Tortoise-ORM Filtering entries that contain a value in a JSONField list with an SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite, tortoise-orm

I'm working on a project that's using Tortoise-ORM v0.18.1 and a SQLite db. I need to find an entry that has a given value inside a json field.

I have a model like this:

```py
class Foo(Model):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=50)
    boo = fields.JSONField()
```

The entries look like this:

```
Foo(name='First', boo=[1, 2, 3])
Foo(name='Second', boo=[4, 5, 6])
Foo(name='Third', boo=[4, 7, 8])
```

I'm looking to filter the entries that have "4" in the "boo" field.

I tried:

```py
entries = await Foo.filter(boo_contains=4)
```

But `entries` contain the three objects instead of just the `Second` and `Third`.

Is there any way i can filter those out?

Documentation says "contains" is valid for text fields **AND** postgresql and MySQL drivers, so there's probably no way but querying all fields and then manually filtering or making a raw SQL query, but I figured it was worth the shot asking here if there.

I guess another option would be to have the `boo` field be a TEXTField and then just use the "contains" operator, I'm not sure if it would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
entries = await Foo.filter(boo__contains=[4])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Anyway this is the way it works.